# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }

Tags: magento2.4.2

In homepage minicart is not working. I upgraded magento to 2.4.2 version

[image: . .]

Comment: Actually, the issue is closeSidebar is not defined. Where and how closeSidebar function is called in JS is not mentioned. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

The method `closeSidebar()` has been removed from 2.4

You need to check if you're overridden `/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html` in your theme

You need to delete `data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()"` and update the data-bind of the close button to:

```
   <button type="button"
                id="btn-minicart-close"
                class="action close"
                data-action="close"
                data-bind="
                attr: {
                    title: $t('Close')
                },
                click: closeMinicart()
            ">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </button>
```

The change is here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/28906

Comment: In my case I don't have the error locally but only on production where mini cart is not rendered. I have been comparing the differences for hours - I still don't get whay closeSidebar() is defined in dev mode but not on prod.

Answer (score 0):

have you find a solution?
I have the same problem.

Comment: copy the vendor folder template